# Moving a Package to PE orgainization

Tags: managed-package

I want to move managed package to PE organization. I am unable to move I Getting an error message saying

1. Missing feature
   Apex Classes
   Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Apex Classes
2. Missing feature
   Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions:WokFlowRule

Can I have the exact steps through which I can deploy the package from my dev org to Professional org

Answer (score 0):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm

> Your app can contain business logic such as classes, triggers, email
>   services, etc. written in Apex. As a general rule, Apex is not
>   supported in GE/PE, so it will not run in these editions. However,
>   Apex developed as part of an ISV app and included in a managed package
>   can run in GE/PE, even though those editions do not support Apex by
>   default.
>
> You must be an eligible partner with salesforce.com and your app has
>   to pass the security review. The appropriate permissions will
>   automatically be enabled after you pass the security review.

Comment: The runned a Security review but still I am unable to deploy the package.Where can review my package

Comment: The Security review results is reviewing my entire code of my organization.I just want security to be reviewed for my managed package.Is that is possible

Comment: The security review only covers your managed package. I am assuming you have an APO and have linked your DE org with the managed package to that APO. Then submitted the package for review?

Comment: What is APO? In the review  it is showing all the other classes which are not included in the managed package

Comment: What do you mean by "In the review"?

Comment: I received an email after review.In That is showing faults other classes

Comment: review-->Security Review/Security check

Comment: @user6833 - Time to read up - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/security_review.htm